# vba Replace everything in sheet using wildcards

Tags: vba, excel

Good afternoon:

Me again ;). Ran into another issue trying to replace all items in a column. I cannot seem to get wildcards to work with how I am invoking my replace statement. Perhaps someone can show me the error in my ways? Thank you.

Code:

```
Worksheets(1).Columns("B").Replace _ 
What:="testName", Replacement:="realName", _ 
SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=false
```

Now this works perfect as long as my data looks like:

```
testname
testName
testNaMe
```

BUT if my data looks like:

```
teestName
TTestname
teesstname
```

This obviously fails. Is there a way to use wildcards with how I am implementing my search, so that I can just search for "name"?  * character doesn't seem to be working as I would think it should(bash user mostly). Thank you.

Comment: Other pages I have viewed seem to be using an extremely different and more robust amount of code compared to the simple task I believe I am trying to accomplish. Perhaps there is a `like` of some sort such that is used in `if` statements I could use?

Comment: Instead of `What:="testname"` try `What:="*testname*"`

Comment: @BruceWayne I could have sworn I have tried that and variations of that for the past 30 minutes and it did not work. Worked first try once you said that...I must have missed something in my original tests.

Comment: You can post it as an answer or I can go ahead and delete this seemingly pointless question now haha. Up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to find "testName" *anywhere* in a cell, then add the `*` wildcard to both sides:

```
Worksheets(1).Columns("B").Replace What:="*testName*", Replacement:="realName", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=false
```

And of course you could also use `="testName*"` or `="*testName"` to match cells that start, or end (respectively) with "testName".